# is it the right reqular expression

Tags: regex

i have following regular expression but it's not working properly it takes only three values after @ sign but i want it to be any number length

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/"
```

this@thi        This is validated
this@this       It is not validating this expression

Can you please tell me what's the problem with the expression...
Thanks

Comment: If this is for email, check out this perl regex, which caters to rfc822: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your regex to match "any number length" then why are you using {2,4}?

I think a better example of the strings you're trying to match might give others a better idea of what you want, because based on your regex it is a bit confusing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$
```

The main problem is that you didn't escape the dot: `\.`. In regular expression the dot matches everything (mostly), making your regex quite liberal.